# Codensity and ContT

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, continuations

While studying functional programming and exploring the concept of continuations, I became acquainted with the types (monad transformers) Codensity and ContT.
They look similar, but it is still not clear how they relate.
It seems like Codensity is more primary than ContT, doesn't it?

In Scala 3, such types can be written like this:

```scala
type Codensity = [F[_]] =>> [A] =>> [B] => (A => F[B]) => F[B]
type ContT     = [F[_]] =>> [A, B]     =>> (A => F[B]) => F[B]
```

How to infer the type of ContT when Codensity is specified (assuming we don’t know in advance what ContT is)?
And on what grounds?
Or some other inference of one type based on another?

Comment: Curried vs. uncurried (with respect to `A`, `B`)

Comment: Uncurrying is not important here. Note the "simple" arrow after `[B]` in the Codensity definition. It's a polymorphic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. The difference is not only in currying (polymorphic function vs. type lambda).

> How to infer the type of ContT when Codensity is specified

How would you answer your question in easier situation?

```scala
type X = [A] =>> List[A]
type Y = [A] => () => List[A] // it would be better to write [A] => List[A]
                              // but it's forbidden in Scala for technical reasons
```

"How to infer the type of `X` when `Y` is specified?"

`X` is a type depending on `A`. `Y` is a type whose term (value) depends on `A`.

`X` is `List`. `Y` is inhabited for example with `Nil[A]` (if we consider invariant list i.e.

```scala
sealed trait List[A]
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case class Nil[A]() extends List[A]
```

instead of

```scala
sealed trait List[+A]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

).

Relation between two types is the following. For a value of type `Y`, this value applied to `A` belongs to the type `X` applied to `A`.

> It seems like Codensity is more primary than ContT, doesn't it?

Is type constructor `List` more primary than polymorphic function `Nil[A]`?

---

```scala
type ContT     = [F[_]] =>> [A, B]     =>> (A => F[B]) => F[B]
type Codensity = [F[_]] =>> [A] =>> [B] => (A => F[B]) => F[B]
```

Here in order to get a proper type (i.e. a type of kind `*`), for `ContT` we have to fix `F`, `A`, `B`, for `Codensity` we have to fix `F`, `A`.

`[B] =>> (A => F[B]) => F[B]` is a type depending on `B`. `[B] => (A => F[B]) => F[B]` is a type whose term depends on `B`.

Relation between two types is the following. For a value of type `Codensity[F][A]`, this value applied to `B` belongs to the type `ContT[F][A, B]`

```scala
type F[_]
type A
type B
type X = ContT[F][A, B]
val x: X = ???
type Y = Codensity[F][A]
val y: Y = ???
y[B]: X
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The last piece of code makes the picture a little clearer. Perhaps I should have formulated my question a little more precisely. Codensity is a right extension of Kahn along the functor itself and this defines the structure of the type. That's why I considered it a given. But it was not clear for what reasons the ContT type could appear. It is similar to Codensity, and it seemed that it could be constructively derived from Codensity based on some additional conditions.

Comment: For example, code has already been written using Codensity. But suddenly the conditions have changed, the code has to be changed, and Codensity is no longer sufficient. Those. we already need another transformer. So I wonder how and why you can get a type similar to ContT?

Comment: @SergeySviridov Just FYI - the Codensity monad has its own transformer.  `type CodensityT = [M[_]] =>> [F[_]] =>> [A] =>> [B] => (A => M[F[B]]) => M[F[B]]` - Maybe that's what you need?